# Behat tests using selenium in a docker environment

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, behat

Hey I am having a 2 containers:
**drupalfront** and **browser**. The drupalfront container has the behat tests and attempts to contact the selenium browser at  http://browser:4444/wd/hub

However, this replies with

```
  **┌─ @BeforeScenario # FeatureContext::resizeWindow()
  │
  ╳  Could not open connection: Unable to create new service: XpiDriverService
  ╳  Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'**
```

Is this the correct configuration for behat?

Answer (score 3):

Behat looks for selenium by default at: `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub`

If you are starting the selenium server on another machine or another port you need to specify this using `wd_host` under `selenium2` in `behat.yml` file.

Examples:

```
wd_host: 'http://192.168.1.2:4444/wd/hub'
```

or if on local machine with different port:

```
wd_host: 'localhost:4445/wd/hub'
```

> Make sure you are using the right driver for your browser.

Comment: what is the default driver for Chrome?

Comment: You need to download the driver based on your os and the current browser version.